# Visual studio is locking up after loading entity framework database connection

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I've created a functioning web api without the connectstrings to hit my database. then I try to code linq into my context class, with no mention to OnModelCreating, stuff, what EF functions can I use without EF taking over my connection to my database and doing ANYTHING I can't control?

Why in gods green earth would I want EF to recreate a high traffic database table and reseed the data?

I don't want something I don't know exactly what its doing to take control of my database.

I can load and run the web api with no errors and no code to show you here about why theres a problem. 
I get no errors and nothing to work with but it puts up a dialog about unloading my projects and not even the task manager can kill the process, I have to disable my connection strings to the database to keep it from locking up. I'm trying to find an alternative to using this "easy" entity framework that takes over for you and does what it pleases. Somebody help me as to why I'm locking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want EF to check or make changes to the DB's schema, or to create a new DB if the DB doesn't exist, then set the initializer to null:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer, I hope this fixes the visual studio locking problem as well